# searching data between dates stored as varchar in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I stored datefield as `varchar`. I want to select the data between two dates and I wrote the query as:

```
SELECT * FROM hospitaldetails WHERE expirydate BETWEEN '03/14/2015' AND '03/18/2015'
```

But it's not working properly. It displays the results of `03/15/2016`. How can I solve it?

Comment: NOTE: MySQL provides native datatypes for storing "date" type values. The datatype is named (rather intuitively) `DATE`.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the varchar data back to dates:

```
Where str_to_date(expirydate, '%m/%d/%Y') between str_to_date('03/14/2015', '%m/%d/%Y') and str_to_date('03/18/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Using varchar data, comparisons are based on lexicographic order. In your case that means the month part of the dates have precedence over the year.

Comment: it showing the error as to_date functions not exist

Comment: Sorry, i was too absent-minded to pay attention to the tags and assumed oracle as the rdbms.

Answer (score 1):

When you store dates as varchar you lose all comparisons for things like between.

Convert the values to date before comparing them to ensure you get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another hint. If you are absolutely stuck with using a varchar field to contain date data, use the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'. That way, a lexical sort will produce the same ordering as converting to date then sorting. However, absolutely if you have the opportunity to change it, make the `expirydate` field an actual date field.